# Why do an XFS volume need to be mounted in order to resize?

Tags: mount, xfs, lvm2

If I have an ext4 volume I can resize it regardless of it being mounted or not using the `resize2fs` command (supplying the device), but for an XFS formatted partition I would need to mount the volume in order to do that (using `xfs_growfs`). Is there a reason for this?

By the way if I want to resize an XFS volume, could I just mount it on a temporary directory and run `xfs_growfs` and then unmount it again? Regardless of it being mounted elsewhere? Or would `xfs_growfs` be dangerous if the same volume is mounted at multiple mount points?

Answer (score 0):

> If I have an ext4 volume I can resize it regardless of it being mounted or not using the resize2fs command (supplying the device), but for an XFS formatted partition I would need to mount the volume in order to do that (using `xfs_growfs`). Is there a reason for this?

For the same reason that there's no tool to shrink an XFS volume, the developers didn't see it as important and therefore never implemented it.  I can actually kind of understand the reasoning for this too.  There are essentially no cases where you will need to resize a volume and can't also mount it, and handling the resize in the kernel code means you don't have to worry about whether the volume is clean or not.

It's probably worth noting that xFS is not unique in this respect, BTRFS also requires a volume to be mounted before it can be resized, and some other filesystems are like this too.  Others are only resizable if unmounted.  The ext2/3/4 formats are actually kind of the odd ones out here in that they can be resized both when mounted and when unmounted.

---

> By the way if I want to resize an XFS volume, could I just mount it on a temporary directory and run `xfs_growfs` and then unmount it again? Regardless of it being mounted elsewhere? Or would `xfs_growfs` be dangerous if the same volume is mounted at multiple mount points?

This is a bit more complicated to answer.  All recent Linux kernels sanely handle multiple mounts of the same volume (internally, there's one mount which all the userspace visible instances reference), and on such kernels, it's perfectly safe to mount an XFS volume a second time somewhere and run `xfs_growfs` on it, though it doesn't really give you any benefits over just calling `xfs_growfs` on the original mountpoint by doing this.  If you're using an older kernel though, or are dealing with shared storage where a different node, you should avoid mounting the volume again regardless of what you are planning to do with the extra mount, as you may destroy it in the process.

Comment: The last sentence seem to be missing something. Could you fix that?

Comment: Regarding your last sentence. Does it imply that mounting a volume again is inherently dangerous? Or is it just in conjunction with `xfs_growfs` the danger arises?